# TASK: Rake aborted! Could not find table 'currencies'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I have deployed my rails app to Linode VPS, using capistrano but thaere is a little snag which I dont know how to solve:

Capistrano output during deployment:

```
==  CreateCurrencies: migrating
-- create_table(:currencies)
-> 0.0074s
==  CreateCurrencies: migrated (0.0075s)
```

Capistrano has created the table currencies, and I can access it on my live server.

I also have a rake task defined as follows:

```
namespace :rate do
  task :update => :environment do
   #Modify Currencies table.
  end
end
```

Now if I run

```
rake rate:update
```

On development machine: Everything works fine.
On production machine: It gives the below error

```
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'currencies'
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: are you running your task on linode in the production environment?  i.e. `RAILS_ENV=production rake rate:update`?  It could be that you are not and that the development database on the Linode has not been migrated.

Comment: @ipd thanks.     running RAILS_ENV=production rake rate:update solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your migartion has not worked from dev mode to production mode. Just check whether you have currencies table in your production db. Also chcek the rails_env when you do run in your production mode.

A sync of all these should fix your problem.